# yet another struggle with django inline formsets

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

Ok, after spending 8 hours of search and read, I think its time to ask. I am creating a school app to practice django, and I am stuck at the grading part. I have a "Matricula" model, that relates a student and a class, and a "Parcial" model that defines a period of time within activities take place. Also, there is a "Grade" model that creates a task to be graded, defined by the "Parcial" and the "Class", and a "Student_Grade" model that will actually relate the "Grade", the "Matricula" and a numeric value (this model is intended to assign a grade for every student).

Here is the scenario:

Models:

```
class Grade(models.Model):

    parcial = models.ForeignKey("configuracion_sam.Estructura_Subperiodo")
    materia = models.ForeignKey("configuracion_sam.Materia")
    type = models.ForeignKey("Grade_Type")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.parcial.name + " " + self.materia.nombre + " " + self.materia.clase.clase_name


class Student_Grade(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey("Grade")
    student = models.ForeignKey("configuracion_sam.Matricula")
    grade = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.assignment.materia.nombre+" "+self.student.estudiante.usuario.name
```

View:

```
def create_grade(request, grade_id):
    grade = Grade.objects.get(pk = grade_id)
    students = Matricula.objects.filter(clase__id = grade.materia.clase_id).order_by("estudiante__usuario__last_name")
    Student_Grade_FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Grade, Student_Grade, extra = len(students))
    context = RequestContext(request)
    formset = Student_Grade_FormSet(instance = grade, initial = students.values())
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = Student_Grade_FormSet(request.POST, instance = grade)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

            return redirect("/faltas/disciplina/")
        else:
            for form in formset:
                print form.errors
                return render_to_response("academic_office_sam/students_grades",
                              {"students":students, "formset":formset},
                              context)

    else:
        return render_to_response("academic_office_sam/students_grades",
                              {"students":students, "formset": formset},
                              context)
```

Notice how in the view I am trying to use inline formsets so that, by assigning a specific "Grade" instance, I can create several registries for several students at the same time. In this case, I am setting extra = len(students) to create a number of forms corresponding to the number of students registered in the same class as the "Grade" is related.

Now the question: How could I set an initial value to the "Matricula" field on the Student_Grade form for every student resulting in the query "students"? I have tried:

```
initial = students
initial = students.values()
queryset = students
queryset = students.values()
```

without success. Maybe it doesnt work as the "Matricula" model is not declared in the formset? I read something about initial parameter only working for the "extra" forms, but I couldnt manage it to show up.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this, and for helping if you can!

Rodrigo

Comment: There are thousands of similar questions about formsets here ... Have you searched?

Comment: As I said, like for 8 hours! Maybe the specificity of this question comes from the need to use values from an extra "model" to fill the values in the form.

Comment: What is `Matricula` (you have not shown it in models) or what keys in `students.values()` dict?  And what logic for select of initial from queryset `students`?

Comment: "Matricula" joins 2 different models, "Students" and "Clases". The logic is that, considering that the "Materia" model created has a "Clase" it belongs to, the students (matricula objects) listed in the inline.form should be the ones that belong to that same "Clase".

Answer (score 0):

```
Student_Grade_FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Grade, Student_Grade, extra=len(students))

if request.POST:
    formset = Student_Grade_FormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.instance = grade
        formset.save()
else:
    formset = Student_Grade_FormSet()

    for inline_form, data in zip(formset.forms, students.values('pk')):
        inline_form.initial = {'student': data}
```